# Using a 3rd Party Library on a Server with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, module

I am writing a script on a remote server in python that just looks at files basically. I want to use some 3rd party librarys that are not bundled with python but I don't think I will have access to install the module on the server

Is there a way to create some sort of a package that I can run that contains all the library that I need?

Comment: yes. Are the libraries pure Python? The answer may depend on the platform.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think so.. I am only trying to use a libary called paramiko

Comment: `paramiko` depends (indirectly) on C openssl library. You could start with `python -mpip install --user paramiko` on the server and report the results.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it just said no module named pip

Comment: is there `pip` command? What about `python3 -mpip`?

Comment: -bash python3 command not found

Comment: why your question has python-3.x tag? Do you want to pack everything into your executable (including `python3` itself)? It might be useful to mention what software your server runs